# How to have different formatting under same fo:block in XSL stylesheet?

Tags: xslt, formatting, stylesheet, xsl-fo, font-size

I have a stylesheet as follows(snippet):

```
<fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="header" text-align-last ="justify">
    <xsl:value-of xsl:use-attribute-sets="branding" select="$pTitle"/>
    <fo:leader leader-pattern = "space" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$vNamer"/>
</fo:block>
```

this lets me render the heading as such:

```
title                                name
------------------------------------------
```

however, I want the "title" to have a different font size(and bolded). how do I apply attributes to "title" only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fo:inline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_inline) to wrap the part you want to apply attributes to.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/):

> Common Usage:
>
> The fo:inline formatting object is commonly used for formatting a
>   portion of text with a background or enclosing it in a border.